# Interact with the DOM of a webview

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-app

All other chrome questions ask on how to edit the webview page and change things in it...

But I want to get an item from a webview and put it on to my app. For example if it were an i frame I would do something like this:

```
var iframe = (tabl.contentDocument) ? tabl.contentDocument : tabl.contentWindow.document;
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = iframe.getElementById("div2").innerHTML;
```

I want to pull information off of the webview for my own use, but every time I try I get the error because one frame is a chrome app and the other is https and its insecure or something

Comment: It would be good to see your error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject javascript into the webview.

Something like this:

```
webview.executeScript({ code: "document.getElementById('myDomElement').innerHTML" }, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The callback returns the last evaluated value.